# Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x76 Spring boot 2.4.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

con este json llamado desde el soap ui

`{
"nombre":"Miriam",
"apellidos": "Conde Rubio",
"fecha_nacimiento":"22-10-1968",
"provincia":"Jaén"
}`

a un servicio rest exactamente a esta operacion

`@RequestMapping(value="/personas/insertar", method=RequestMethod.POST,
consumes = { "application/json; charset=utf-8" }, produces = { "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
public ResponseEntity insertarPersonas(@RequestBody MSEListadoPersonas personas);`

Me devuelve ese error, y no debería porque el consume tengo añadido el utf-8. ¿Sabeis cual puede ser el mótivo?

Comment: Pon tus headers del soap UI, yo creo que te falta el header Content-Type con el valor application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: nono, eso también lo tengo añadido

Comment: como dije, pon tus headers del soap UI